# Flutter TextPainter - center char inside circle

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, text, center

I need to draw circle + one character inside circle. Character should be centered inside my circle, how do I do that? My code:

```
class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {

  String text;
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint1 = Paint()
      ..color = Color(Colors.blueGrey.value + 100*text.codeUnitAt(0))
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, 0), 20, paint1);

    TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
        text: text.toUpperCase(),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: AppTheme.fontName,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 22,
          color: Colors.white,));

    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
        text: span,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);

    tp.layout(minWidth: 20, maxWidth: 20);


    tp.paint(canvas, Offset(-10.0, -10.0));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

With my current approach still some letters are not correctly centered (horizontal and vertical directions) inside my circle. What is valid solution?

Comment: did you find any sol ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project I did that needed a single character inside a circle with a stroke, custom painted.

```
class DrawCircle extends CustomPainter {
  String title = "D";
  var paint1 = Paint()..color = Colors.redAccent;
  var paint2 = Paint()..color = Colors.amber;

  TextStyle textStyle = const TextStyle(
    color: Color(0xff050505),
    fontSize: 43,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  );

  /// Creating a TextPainter object.
  TextPainter text_painter = TextPainter(
    // text: span,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    textDirection: UI.TextDirection.ltr,
  );

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // set style
    text_painter.text = TextSpan(
      text: title.toString(),
      style: textStyle,
    );

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0.0, 0.0), 50, paint1);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0.0, 0.0), 40, paint2);
    text_painter.layout();
    //center the text inside the circle => manually
    text_painter.paint(canvas, const Offset(-15.0, -25.0));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```